# Graphics: How to Fill Color Between Lines?

Tags: python, graphics, fill, area, zelle-graphics

I am trying to design a QR-Code in a circular shape. I have to code it with python but I don't have much experience about it. After a lot of effort I created the shapes. Now I need to fill color between these shapes but I couldn't make it. My output graphic curently looks like this:

[image: screenshot of current output]

I need to fill those empty shapes with color. The code that I implemented to create this graphic is given below. I am not sure if I am using the right library. I saw lots of examples about matplotlib.pyplot but I thought it is more useful for creating charts. So any contribution is appreciated. I am really stuck.

```
from graphics import *
import math

def rect(r, theta):
    """theta in degrees

    returns tuple; (float, float); (x,y)
    """
    x = r * math.cos(math.radians(theta))
    y = r * math.sin(math.radians(theta))
    return x, y


def polar(x, y):
    """returns r, theta(degrees)
    """
    r = (x ** 2 + y ** 2) ** .5
    if y == 0:
        theta = 180 if x < 0 else 0
    elif x == 0:
        theta = 90 if y > 0 else 270
    else:
        theta = math.degrees(math.atan(float(y) / x))
    return r, theta


def main():
    win = GraphWin('Canvas', 640, 480)  # give title and dimensions
    win.setCoords(-320, -240, 320, 240)

    seventh = Circle(Point(0, 0), 90)  # set center and radius
    # seventh.setFill("yellow")
    seventh.draw(win)

    sixth = Circle(Point(0, 0), 80)  # set center and radius
    # sixth.setFill("yellow")
    sixth.draw(win)

    fifth = Circle(Point(0, 0), 70)  # set center and radius
    # fifth.setFill("yellow")
    fifth.draw(win)

    fourth = Circle(Point(0, 0), 60)  # set center and radius
    # fourth.setFill("yellow")
    fourth.draw(win)

    third = Circle(Point(0, 0), 50)  # set center and radius
    # third.setFill("yellow")
    third.draw(win)

    second = Circle(Point(0, 0), 40)  # set center and radius
    # second.setFill("yellow")
    second.draw(win)

    first = Circle(Point(0, 0), 30)  # set center and radius
    # first.setFill("yellow")
    first.draw(win)

    line = Line(Point(0, 0), Point(rect(90, 0)[0], rect(90, 0)[1]))
    line.draw(win)

    line2 = Line(Point(0, 0), Point(rect(90, 30)[0], rect(90, 30)[1]))
    line2.draw(win)

    line3 = Line(Point(0, 0), Point(rect(90, 60)[0], rect(90, 60)[1]))
    line3.draw(win)

    line4 = Line(Point(0, 0), Point(rect(90, 90)[0], rect(90, 90)[1]))
    line4.draw(win)

    line5 = Line(Point(0, 0), Point(rect(90, 120)[0], rect(90, 120)[1]))
    line5.draw(win)

    line6 = Line(Point(0, 0), Point(rect(90, 150)[0], rect(90, 150)[1]))
    line6.draw(win)

    line7 = Line(Point(0, 0), Point(rect(90, 180)[0], rect(90, 180)[1]))
    line7.draw(win)

    line8 = Line(Point(0, 0), Point(rect(90, 210)[0], rect(90, 210)[1]))
    line8.draw(win)

    line9 = Line(Point(0, 0), Point(rect(90, 240)[0], rect(90, 240)[1]))
    line9.draw(win)

    line10 = Line(Point(0, 0), Point(rect(90, 270)[0], rect(90, 270)[1]))
    line10.draw(win)

    line11 = Line(Point(0, 0), Point(rect(90, 300)[0], rect(90, 300)[1]))
    line11.draw(win)

    line12 = Line(Point(0, 0), Point(rect(90, 330)[0], rect(90, 330)[1]))
    line12.draw(win)

    line13 = Line(Point(0, 0), Point(rect(90, 360)[0], rect(90, 360)[1]))
    line13.draw(win)

    line14 = Line(Point(0, 0), Point(rect(90, 210)[0], rect(90, 210)[1]))
    line14.draw(win)

    first.setFill('black')


    message = Text(Point(0, 200), 'Click anywhere to quit.')
    message.draw(win)
    win.getMouse()

    win.close()

main()
```

If I can achieve it, I want to draw a picture that looks like this (drawn in Photoshop):

[image: screenshot of desired image created with Photoshop]

After some helpful comments I decided to find another appropriate python module. But I couldn't find the right one. If are there anyone who understand my problem can suggest the appropriate python module?

Comment: You are aware that qr-codes encode data in its "shape" so by designing a round qr-code you create random data? what is that good for?

Comment: @PatrickArtner I know qr-codes encode data in its own shape. I am trying to design a circular 2D-barcode which have lots in common with original qr code. But my problem, I couldn't achieve to fill between those lines with this library.

Comment: You've got all the `setFill()` calls commented-out. What colors to you want between what lines?

Comment: John Zelle's `graphics.py` module is built on top of `tkinter`, so using it directly might give you more control. If not, you might want to the Zelle module's `Polygon` shape which should allow to color the interior of arbitrary shapes if you can provide a list of vertices comprising the outline of the area to be filled.

Comment: @martineau setFill() is filling the whole circle but I need to fill the area surrounded by two circles and two lines. In the picture there are 72 of them. Now, I can describe one of them with for example **seventh**, **sixth**, **line2** and **line3** objects. If I can fill the area described by these objects, I can fill the area which I want. I draw the photoshop of what I want at the end I will edit my question by adding that picture. Thank you.

Comment: Neither the `graphics` nor `tkinter` (or `pygame`) modules support polygon shapes with holes in them which is what would be needed to explicitly do what you want. Instead, you may be able to fake it by drawing two concentric circles, the first filled with the color between the lines you want, and a second smaller one that is filled with the color of background thereby effectively erasing part of the interior of the first one drawn.

Comment: @martineau Yes I thought your suggestion too. But with this approach I still cant paint the area that I want. It fills whole area beween two circles.

Comment: Fatih: OK, now that I've seen what you want, I must correct my previous comments about not being able to do this with the Zelle `graphics` module. It is possible, since it doesn't look like it requires anything it couldn't do—however doing so would not be especially easy. Basically you'd need to calculate a set of points representing the shape of the each area you want and then use those to create a filled `Polygon` for each one.

Comment: You might be able to do it with the `tkinter` module which has the ability to draw arcs with wide lines. You can see an example of doing this is in [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46166494/355230) of mine to another question. You could even add a new type of shape class to the Zelle `graphics` module that does something along those lines.

Answer (score 1):

I believe Python turtle, also built on tkinter, has enough capability to simulate your circular QR-Code with more intuitive logic:

```
from math import pi, sin, cos
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

TWO_PI = pi * 2

SEGMENTS = 10  # pie slices
SECTORS = 8  # concentric circles
MAXIMUM_RADIUS = 100
MINIMUM_RADIUS = 10
DELTA_RADIUS = (MAXIMUM_RADIUS - MINIMUM_RADIUS) // SECTORS
SEGMENT_EXTENT = TWO_PI / SEGMENTS
DEFAULT_LINE_WIDTH = 1

DATA = [  # data to match OP's example chart
    (2, 0), (2, 3), (2, 5), (2, 6), (2, 9),
    (3, 0), (3, 1), (3, 3), (3, 4), (3, 6),
    (4, 1), (4, 2), (4, 7), (4, 8),
    (5, 0), (5, 1), (5, 4), (5, 5), (5, 6), (5, 7),
    (6, 3), (6, 5), (6, 8), (6, 9),
    (7, 0), (7, 2), (7, 3), (7, 4), (7, 5), (7, 6), (7, 8),
    ]

def centered_circle(turtle, radius, extent=TWO_PI):
    """ draw a circle centered about the current turtle location """

    position = turtle.position()
    heading = turtle.heading()

    turtle.penup()
    turtle.setx(turtle.xcor() + cos(heading) * radius)
    turtle.sety(turtle.ycor() - sin(heading) * radius)
    turtle.pendown()

    turtle.circle(radius, extent, steps=60)

    turtle.penup()
    turtle.setposition(position)  # return turtle to starting position
    turtle.pendown()

def draw_blank_chart(turtle):
    """ draw the empty chart """

    turtle.dot(MINIMUM_RADIUS * 2)  # center of chart

    for radius in range(MINIMUM_RADIUS + DELTA_RADIUS, MAXIMUM_RADIUS + 1, DELTA_RADIUS):
        centered_circle(turtle, radius)  # divide chart into sectors

    turtle.width(2 * DELTA_RADIUS / 3)  # outer edge of chart
    centered_circle(turtle, MAXIMUM_RADIUS + DELTA_RADIUS)
    turtle.width(DEFAULT_LINE_WIDTH)

    for _ in range(SEGMENTS):  # divide chart into segments
        turtle.forward(MAXIMUM_RADIUS + DELTA_RADIUS)
        turtle.backward(MAXIMUM_RADIUS + DELTA_RADIUS)
        turtle.left(SEGMENT_EXTENT)

def set_bit(turtle, sector, segment):
    """ turn on (blacken) one sector:segment of chart """

    turtle.setheading(SEGMENT_EXTENT * segment - pi/2)
    turtle.width(DELTA_RADIUS)
    centered_circle(turtle, (MINIMUM_RADIUS + DELTA_RADIUS * sector + DELTA_RADIUS/2), -SEGMENT_EXTENT)

screen = Screen()
screen.mode('logo')  # force zero degrees to be straight up

yertle = Turtle(visible=False)
yertle.width(DEFAULT_LINE_WIDTH)
yertle.speed('fastest')
yertle.radians()  # to make working with sin and cos easier

draw_blank_chart(yertle)

for sector, segment in DATA:
    set_bit(yertle, sector, segment)

screen.exitonclick()
```

[image]